# AngularJs ui-router success transition get the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created a service that is to run any http requests that have been requested. This runs in the ui-router onSuccess hook and looks like this:

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    console.log('%cwe have completed a transition', 'color: green;');
    httpQueueService.process();
});
```

The problem with this is that the controller is initialized after this hook, so I can't capture the http requests without adding a timeout:

```
function process() {
    $timeout(() => {
        let t = angular.copy(queue);
        console.log('processing', t, t.length);
        queue.forEach((task) => invoke(task));
    }, 500);
}
```

I know the timeout is only half a second and I could probably reduce that even futher, but it doesn't seem right.
It would be better if I could get the controller that has been initialized directly from the success hook.

Is there a way of doing this?

I did try by looking at the transition object in the success hook:

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {
    console.log(transition);
});
```

But that doesn't appear to have the controller there

Comment: Which 'controller is initialized after this hook' can you explain better?

Comment: Not sure how to explain it better. I mean the controller of the state that has successfully transitioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the 'resolve' option of the ui-router's states. You are trying to asynchronously load data (from your httpQueueService) to the new state's controller if I understood your description correctly. I suggest you take a look at the official ui-router documentation, especially the tutorials. Obviously you can skip most of it, so starting from the second: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem seems feasible for you.

Basically it handles the asynchronous nature of what you are doing - without adding any exact, hard-coded timeout.

Here is another great article which I found helpful when dealt with async queries on transitions: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c

I hope this helps, however, if you have any more specific issue then let us know!